# android listView change dynamically

Tags: android, listview

i have a list and corresponding adaptor. in list i have 20 items which is stored in an array. a event occurred and my list size decreased to 10 items(now in array 10 items are present). i call `notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the list. but i am getting null pointer exception. i think this is because this method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

is calling 20 times and I have only 10 item so array[position] is returning null at position=11 in getView Method. am i thinking in right direction? i want to know more about getView but android documentation is not sufficient for  me to understand the things.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix

```
public int getCount ()
```

to **return the correct count**

Answer (score 0):

u can use handler to change list view dynamically

```
private final Handler mHandler=new Handler() 
{       
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
        list.invalidate();
        return;
    }
};
```

if u want call handler use

```
handler.sendemptymessage(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should reset the array list in adapter class (i.e at the time of calling notifyDatasetChanged() the array list should have that 10 items.

Comment: i have updated the arraylist but getView method is calling 20 times ( i think) and sinch i have 10 item in arraylist so i am getting error

Comment: create new instance of array list and load that 10 items or remove items from existing array list and then call notifydatasetchanged.